# How to access a class's property inside another generic class by object passing?

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance

In my code, Generic class Public will receive a generic object in check() method. These generic objects might be from JuniorInstructor class or SeniorInstructor class.I wanna access the properties of JuniorInstructor class or SeniorInstructor class. I tried with below implementation and it works. But, Is there any better way to do this?

```
   class JuniorInstructor extends Instructor {

    public JuniorInstructor(String id, String name) {
        super(id, name);

    }

}

class Public<T> {
    T object;
    JuniorInstructor j1;
    SeniorInstructor s1;

    public void check(T object) {

        this.object = object;
        if (object instanceof SeniorInstructor) {
            s1 = (SeniorInstructor) object;
            System.out.println("name: " + s1.name + "\tid: " + s1.id);
        } else {
            j1 = (JuniorInstructor) object;
            System.out.println("name: " + j1.name + "\tid: " + j1.id);
        }
    }// check
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SeniorInstructor s1 = new SeniorInstructor("120", "Ashik");
        JuniorInstructor j1 = new JuniorInstructor("677", "Tareq");
        Public p = new Public();

        p.check(j1);

    }
```

Comment: I think you are using generics the wrong way. One of the benefits of generics is that you can write _generic_ code, without the need for using `instanceof` and casting etc...

Comment: Does SeniorInstructor implement Instructor? If it does, is T really intended to be completely generic or is it supposed to extend Instructor? --> This might help you find the answer.

Comment: You're also missing the whold point of polymorphism. The class shouldn't be generic. And it should not have any state. And its method should simply take an Instructor as argument: `class Public {
    public void check(Instructor instructor) {
        System.out.println("name: " + instructor.getName() + "\tid: " + instructor.getId()); } }`

Comment: You don't need of class generic if you don't infer the type to the subclasses. The point of making class generic is to use it with different types.

Comment: @Ward I did not have any idea how to implement the scenario by generics. Some guys answered and my problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

You can further qualify `T`:

```
class Public<T extends Instructor>
```

And simply make sure all the methods you need to access are defined on `Instructor`. You'll then be able to call them directly in `Public`.

[Edit] @JBNizet has an excellent point in comments that `Public` doesn't really need to be generics if `Instructor` and its subclasses are all it needs to handle.

Comment: Thank you. It works. you make the concept clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the Public class like

```
class Public<T extends Instructor> {
      ...
   }
```

in this way you can avoid to check for instance type, as long as you need to access to 'Instructor' property.

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you. It works. you make the concept clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think might want to use *polymorphism* instead of *generics*.

Create 2 overloaded versions of `check` method:

- one that accepts a `JuniorInstructor`
- one that accepts a `SeniorInstructor`

In this way, there is no need to use `instanceOf` or casting objects to a given type.

```
class Public {
    JuniorInstructor j1;
    SeniorInstructor s1;

    public void check(SeniorInstructor object) {
        s1 = object;
        System.out.println("name: " + s1.getName() + "\tid: " + s1.getId());
    }

    public void check(JuniorInstructor object) {
        j1 = object;
        System.out.println("name: " + j1.getName() + "\tid: " + j1.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Or if you don't even need to store references to `JuniorInstructor` or `SeniorInstructor` in your `Public` class, but just print out their `name` and `id`, the comment of JB Nizet on your question is even better.

Answer (score 0):

As Ward mentioned,

> One of the benefits of generics is that you can write generic code, without the need for using instanceof and casting etc...

You can modify the Public class as below :

```
class Public<T extends Instructor> {
   T instructor;

   public void check(T object) {
       this.instructor = object;
       System.out.println("name: " + this.instructor.name + "\tid: " + this.instructor.id);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Instructor {

private String id;
private String name;

public Instructor(String id, String name) {
        this.id= id; this.name= name;
}

//getters and setters
 }
```

Then a class public :

```
class Public<T extends Instructor> {
T object;

public void check(T object) {
        System.out.println("name: " + object.getName() + "\tid: " + object.getId());
}
}
```

However, if your class has only 1 method using this T as parameter, you can modify it to:

```
class Public {

public <T extends Instructor> void check(T object) {
        System.out.println("name: " + object.getName() + "\tid: " + object.getId());
}
 }
```

Or since usage of generics is not clear here, we can simply use:

```
class Public {

public  void check(Instructor object) {
        System.out.println("name: " + object.getName() + "\tid: " + object.getId());
}
 }
```

And in main:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Public obj= new Public();
    obj.check(new JuniorInstructor("1","Payal"));
}
```